# what is the best route for my shed? what amperage should I use?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

ok...so...I am undecided what to use to power up this detached shed, which is 70 feet away from the main panel. I obviously want to go the safest route (shed is 200 square feet) Before hand, I really want to go the 30amp route, due to its cost friendly ways and I dont think I am going to use that much power; just want some opinions.

route 1 -

Use a double pole 60amp with #6-3 UF wire to feed a 60amp sub panel in the detached shed? (wire will be buried)

route 2 -

use a double pole 30amp 10-3 wire UF rated to feed a 50 or 60amp sub panel in the detached shed and use pvc conduit for the wire (or does NEC only allow direct burial with no conduit for UF wire?

what I plan on using in the shed - 
3 security cameras
5 outlets (GFCI)
power tools such as table saws and vacuums 
small TV and leave batteries charging

thats about it....

what is the best route?

Comment: It really comes down to whatever you plan to run at once, but assuming 200W per rcpt, 200W per battery, 200W for TV, 1800W for table saw, 1500W for shop vac, and like 100W for all the cameras. You're looking at like 5kW reasonable with everything on, which is like 21A on the panel.

This is all variable. But you could definitely cover it with a 30A. But, at the same time, I'd say this is your only chance to get more power without digging up the line, and you're already buying a 60A panel regardless.

Comment: i suppose worst case power load is if you want to run the vac to collect dust from a tool as it is operating..now pushing close to 30 amp right there.

Answer (score 2):

A 30 amp and 60 amp two pole breaker are basically the same price.

The panel is the same price in both scenarios.

The labor to install it is practically the same.

The only difference is the price of the wire.

For 70 feet of wire price difference I wouldn't skimp on this one.

I would go for scenario #1 and have enough capacity for future expansion.

Good luck!

Comment: I agree with #1 , 30 amps for a work shop is just enough to have you kicking yourself every time you have to reset the breaker and the work putting this in is the real cost.